# Dividindo números inteiros no MS Excel (divisão exata)

Tags: microsoft-excel

Estou com um problema no Excel que eu achava que ia ser fácil resolver, mas to quebrando a cabeça é o seguinte:
Tenho uma grade de pedido, por exemplo, 2.010 pares, e o controle de produção e a ordem de produção, é de 10 em 10, preciso calcular quantas ordens de produção precisaria fazer para produzir esse pedido, sendo que o valor médio em um ordem de produção é 300, 320, 330, 340 até no máximo 360 (pois senão sobrecarrega a máquina)

Então, como o pedido é 2010 pares, e eu for dividir por 340 por exemplo, fica 5,91 ops, da um número decimal. O que eu queria era uma função ou fórmula, em que o Excel não quebrasse, onde nesse exemplo, o valor de saída seria: 5 ops de 340 e 1 de 310, totalizando as 2010 peças. Tem como fazer isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar a fórmula `=ARREDONDAR.PARA.BAIXO(A2/B2;0)` para calcular o número inteiro, e a quantidade na OP com o restante seria de acordo com a fórmula `=A2-B2*C2`.

Assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Daí você pode ir brincando com a coluna B para chegar em um valor que lhe agrada nas colunas C e D.

Comment: perfeito Cara, simples e intuitivo. Muito Obrigado!

Comment: Seguindo a mesma lógica acima, tem uns pedidos que vem com a grade 2.864, e como o controle é feito de 10 em 10, tem alguma função para o excel arredondar sempre para cima?, nesse caso ficaria 2870.

Comment: Abre outra pergunta se precisar...

Answer (score 0):

Outra possibilidade é usar as funções TRUNCAR e MOD.
A função TRUNCAR(número;[núm_dígitos]) remove a parte fracionária de um número.
A função MOD(número,divisor) retorna o resto de uma divisão.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).